# Trigger do not see other schema even though it exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create trigger so that when we are logging in as application users we don't need to specify the schema prefix for tables. But I am struggling with the error. The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_schema.db_logon_app
AFTER LOGON ON app_schema.schema
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = DB_SCHEMA';
END;
```

When I try to execute it the following error appears:

> Error report:
>   ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

How to deal with it? Both of the schemas exists and the `DB_SCHEMA` has `ALTER SESSION` privilege.

When I am trying to create such trigger just to check that it works everything is fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER db_schema.db_logon_app
AFTER LOGON ON db_schema.schema
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = DB_SCHEMA';
END;
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [synonyms](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401) ?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying the dynamic `alter session` fails with 'table or view does not exist'? That sounds odd. It doesn't refer to any table or view.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson no, it seems it does not see the `APP_SCHEMA` because when I try to create trigger for my current schema itself - it works.

Comment: What can't 'see' the schema? The trigger itself or some query that you run subsequently? If the schema name was invalid, the `alter session` command should give `ORA-01435: user does not exist`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson see the edited version. Sorry I had typo in original version

Comment: `Alter session` privileges is not needed for set current_schema

Comment: I think the trigger name must be just `db_logon_app`, however using SYNONYMS would be a much better solution. Or execute the alter session command in your application.

Comment: I can't do a test right now but it seems odd that `DB_SCHEMA` should own a system trigger that fires on a connection to `APP_SCHEMA`. What if you remove the `db_schema.` prefix from the `create` line? (Though I'm still not sure why it would give you an error message about tables and views.)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Can you explain how to do it with synonyms?

Comment: Just create SYNONYM for each TABLE, PACKAGE, VIEW, etc. see [CREATE SYNONYM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401). This one may also help https://coderanch.com/t/563170/application-servers/PL-SQL-create-synonyms-tables